# Mysql searching Column with beginning of words

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Data in column like below

```
ferrari motor
motor
tata motor
motor corp
hundai motor
```

So When I use this query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('%motor' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10
```

I get results in random order like below

```
tata motor
motor corp
ferrari motor
motor
hundai motor
```

But I want to sort it in the way if the **motor** is starting word it should be given priority , So my expected result should be like below

```
motor
motor corp
tata motor
ferrari motor
hundai motor
```

P.S  :  If it is not possible with `Full text` , Answer using `LIKE`  is also welcome  , which should also support multiple words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to sort by the position of the searched string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('%motor' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY INSTR(UPPER(`name`), UPPER('motor'))
LIMIT 10
```

This would give you

```
motor
motor corp
tata motor
hundai Motor
ferrari motor
```

or

```
motor corp
motor
tata motor
hundai Motor
ferrari motor
```

If you need 'motor' to come before 'motor corp' then add another criterion like

```
ORDER BY INSTR(UPPER(`name`), UPPER('motor')), LENGTH(`name`)
```

Answer (score 0):

USE a order by case to give special occasions special priority.

```
SELECT * FROM view_sample
WHERE ...
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN name LIKE 'motor%' THEN 2 
    WHEN name LIKE '%motor%' THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END, 
 name
```

1. everything thats starts with motor
2. everything that includes at least motor
3. everything else ...

sorted by name

In your case, the ordering would be:

```
motor
motor corp
ferrari motor
hundai motor
tata motor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union which selects first the results with motor% and later the others.

```
(select 1, name
   from carcomp
  where name like 'motor%')
union
(select 2, name
   from carcomp
  where name like '%motor%' 
    and not like 'motor%')
order by 1,2
```

Comment: that is a bit overkill isnt it? just order by CASE

Comment: It depends, my response works on other dbs as well, not only mysql, and the optimizer can run both queries at once, if it is smart enough. Didn't run benchmarks, though.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about MySQL syntax, but something like:

```
ORDER BY case when SUBSTRING(columnname,1,5) = 'motor' then 0 else 1 end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `instr()` or `locate()` to order the results by where `'motor'` appears in the string.

```
order by (name = 'motor') desc, instr(name, 'motor')
```

The first clause puts the exact match first.

In your case, the ordering would be:

```
motor
motor corp
tata motor
hundai motor
ferrari motor
```

Comment: isnt the first order clause missing a function name or anything? name= 'motor' seems new to me.

Comment: @Umingo . . . In a numeric context, MySQL treats booleans as numbers with true being 1 and false being 0.  This is a nice convenience, but not one supported by other databases.  The standard alternative would be to use `case`.

Comment: but what if name is more than motor .. like motor toyota. all that is doing if in case that name is exactly motor, put it to the front. right?

Comment: @umingo . . . Yes, it is putting the exact match first and ordering the rest by the position of `'motor'` in the name.

Comment: sorry, my fault, I did use the ios client wrong, resulting in a downvote. now i cant remove it until the answer is edited :-(

Comment: @thst . . . I was just curious why.  Thanks for explaining.